# Grails Rendering Plugin error when trying to render PDF?

Tags: grails, plugins

When using the Grails Rendering plugin i am getting an error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox[C] . We are also using the Jasper Plugin which uses a new version of the iText library. I guess there is a mismatch between the 2 plugins..

Any idea how to fix this?

/Marco

Answer (score 3):

Your probably right there with the assumption there are two versions of iText. I have had lots of fun with iText conflicts in the past. I don't use the Jasper Plugin so I can't give you the direct answer, but I can recommend a couple of things to try:

1. Use the command *grails dependency report* to see what exactly is going on, which version of iText is kept, and which is being kicked out.
2. In your build config you can manage the dependencies of a particular plugin. So might be able to get away with removing the Jasper Plugin dependency on itext. Here is an example from mine for the export plugin:

   runtime(':export:1.1') {
           excludes 'itext', 'itext-rtf'
   }